# Cannot find class (C3P0 sources.jar)

Tags: java, apache, c3p0

I want to introduce Connection Pooling to my application and decided to use C3P0. Nevertheless, for some weird reason when I import both JAR files, Netbeans can't find the classes that the documentation tells me I should use.

Here is a setup of my project:

[image]

Any insights? Is there a special way to add this jars? I did it the way I added the database driver and other libraries and I didn't get issues with those.

I copied the `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.*` manually from the documentation page here: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#quickstart

Comment: Are you sure that `machange-commons-java-0.2` actually contains the package `com.machange.v2.c3po` and a class called `ComboPooledDataSource`. Just getting the basics out the way first.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I didn't code it, but I'd assume it is, since that's what the documentation says I should install and then code =/

Comment: I don't see it in the list [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmchangecommonsjava0234jar.htm). But again, you could be using a different version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you downloaded the [c3p0-0.9.5-sources.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadc3p00912sourcesjar.htm) that contains the `.java` source files instead of the binary distributable. The compiler only looks for `.class` files when searching for dependenies of a class and not `.java` files.

You should download the `c3p0` `jar` that contains the `.class` files. ([This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadc3p0095pre1jar.htm) one for example)

Comment: Whoops, that was a dumb mistake. You're right, I picked the wrong jars. Thanks a lot